# When unit-testing email method, stub jakarta.mail.Transport(message) and do nothing on that sub-method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm testing the following method which includes a call to `jakarta.mail.Transport(message)` to send out an actual email:

```
public static void sendEmail(String emailSmtpHost, Integer emailSmtpPort, String emailAddressFrom, String emailAddressTo, String emailSubject, String emailBody) {
    
    try {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put(Constants.MAIL_SMTP_HOST_PROPERTY_NAME, emailSmtpHost);
        props.put(Constants.MAIL_SMTP_PORT_PROPERTY_NAME, emailSmtpPort);
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
        msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailAddressFrom));
        msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(emailAddressFrom, false));
        msg.setSubject(emailSubject, "UTF-8");
        msg.setText(emailBody, "UTF-8");
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(emailAddressTo, false));
        Transport.send(msg);

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error when sending email: ", e);     
    }
```

To unit-test this method, I'll make sure all the values are set on the Message, but I want to avoid the actual sub-method call of `Transport.send(msg)`. How do I do it?

This doesn't work:

```
    Transport transportSpy = Mockito.spy(new Transport());
    doNothing().when(transportSpy).send(Mockito.any());
```

I can't instantiate `Transport`. I need to specifically block the static method `Transport.send()`.

Answer (score 1):

This could help you with that:

https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods

1. Configure Mockito to allow inline MockMaker:
   Add a file in `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions` named `org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing `mock-maker-inline`
2. Create mock in test

```
@Test
void testSendEmail() {

    try (MockedStatic<Transport> transport = Mockito.mockStatic(Transport.class)) {
        transport.when(() -> Transport.send(/*testdata*/))
          .thenReturn(/*return value*/);

        //test
    }

   
}
```

The function is only mocked inside the try clause.